# What the difference between linux commands ps -ef | grep [W]DA and ps -ef | grep WDA?

Tags: linux, command

What the difference between linux commands `ps -ef | grep [W]DA` and `ps -ef | grep WDA` ??

Comment: The first one greps for a regex that has as its first element a group consisting only of the character "W". It expects one value out of this group and as this group consists only of one element the command behaves just like the second one that expects the character "W" at the first position.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that for the latter, as one of the results, you get the `grep WDA` in the results of `ps`. If you add the square brackets then `grep` doesn't find `[W]DA` in the resulting output of `ps -ef`, because there is no such process containing square brackets in its name.

To illustrate how it works (to get results faster I used `sshd` instead of `WDA` on my console):

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
root      1046     1  0 06:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
rogus     2321  1189  0 07:30 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd

ps -ef | grep [s]shd
root      1046     1  0 06:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

The position of the square bracket is arbitrary, it doesn't matter which character you choose as long as it has one character only (if you'd use `[WD]A` then `grep` would look for either `WA` or `DA`)

The main usage is with analyzing output and getting rid of the unwanted piped grep. If you use it e.g. in a `for` loop and analyze each line containg data for different process instances, then the `grep WDA` would be used in the loop which is most probably not intended.

Comment: Thank you! 
And do you know how exactly [?] rids the unwanted info ?